# Issues with new java update

Tags: java, eclipse

More issues with java. I just updated to the newest version of the java jdk and now none of my code is working. Eclipse is saying the type string does not exist, it is not finding the Scanner type in java.util, and I have no idea what happened. I don't know if java majorly changed or what. (Note the version I updated to was java 8 update 92)

Comment: try to clean build the project...

Comment: clean all projects and if it still shows , click on fix project and just click ok

Comment: You might need to setup again your environment variables. JAVA_HOME might be pointing to old Java version I guess

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, go to:

`Window -> Preferences -> Java (open sub-menu) -> Installed JREs`.

Then remove the old entries.

Press `Add -> Standard VM`, and specify the new jdk folder you've downloaded.
Its default location is in `C:/Program Files/Java`.